# Load image to imageview directly using aws s3 without downloading to local storage in android

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, android-studio, digital-ocean

Iam loading images from the digital ocean spaces using aws s3 now its download the image to the local storage and then loading the image in image view but i need to load the image directly without downloading the image in local

My Current Code:

```
AmazonS3Client s3;
    BasicAWSCredentials credentials;
    TransferUtility transferUtility;
    final TransferObserver observer,observers;
    String key = "XXXXXXXX";
    String secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX";

    credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(key, secret);
    s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
    s3.setEndpoint("https://xxx.yyyy.com");

    transferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3, getApplicationContext());
    CannedAccessControlList filePermission = CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead;

    observer = transferUtility.download(
            "xxx",
            "xxxx/01.jpg",
            new File("/storage/emulated/0/camera 1/05.jpg")
    );

    observer.setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
            if (state.COMPLETED.equals(observer.getState())) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Space Download completed !!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/storage/emulated/0/camera 1/05.jpg");
                imgview.setImageBitmap(bmp);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Space Download error: " + ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Try using image loading libraries like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

Comment: Directly i cant get the url of the image i need to authenticate with spaces key in digital ocean @Shashanth

Comment: You can generate a pre-signed URL for the key and then use the URL with a tool of your choice such as Glide to download the image. See https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/blob/master/aws-android-sdk-s3/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.java#L3221

Comment: @Karthikeyan great job! Worked for me

Comment: @Karthikeyan Thank you so much bro you my time pre-signed URL this keyword helped me a lot bro Great...

Comment: Great. Thanks for confirming!

Comment: Beware of the fact that the presigned URL has an expiration and you need to generate a new URL when the URL expires. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@karthikeyan comment helped me here is the answer:

```
    AmazonS3Client s3;
    BasicAWSCredentials credentials;

    String key = "xxxxx"; //SpacesKey
    String secret = "yyyyyyyyy"; //Spaces Secret key

    credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(key, secret);
    s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);

    s3.setEndpoint("https://RegionName.digitaloceanspaces.com"); //endpoint

    Date expires = new Date (new Date().getTime() + 1000 * 60); // 1 minute to expire
    GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, objectKey);  //generating the signatured url

    generatePresignedUrlRequest.setExpiration(expires);
    URL url = s3.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest);
```

load the image to image view using Picasso or Glide with the url

Comment: Beware of the fact that the presigned URL has an expiration and you need to generate a new URL when the URL expires. Thanks!

Comment: @Karthikeyan yes bro i saw those things i completed the tasks

Comment: @JôhÑsk what is the objectkey ?

Comment: One issue is changing URL after every minute won't let the library cache the image and not caching images served from cloud can lead to a high amount of data transfer charges.

Comment: this is not working, may be due AmazonS3Client, because it says deprecated, and what about cache as  @Asif Saeed mentioned, that it will call it again as url changing

Comment: What is the name of that lib? Is it on Github or similar? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

1. You can use **Picasso** for loading image from a url. 
   Here is an example -

Use Gradle In App Level:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

Use this line to load image from your url -

```
Picasso.get().load("https://xxx.yyyy.com/your_image.png").into(imageView); // Your imageview
```

2. Glide also a solution

Use Gradle:

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral() 
  google()
}

dependencies {
   implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
   annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
}



// For a simple view:
  Glide.with(this).load("https://xxx.yyyy.com/your_image.png").into(imageView);
```

3. Fresco is also a powerful system for displaying images in Android Developed by **facebook**.

**Enjoy android**

Comment: but i need to authenticate with the digitalocean spaces. like endpoint bucket name key value

Comment: You can generate your url dynamically with some logic.

Comment: thanks for your comment i done it and also i posted the answer